# When will my new sitemap be indexed by Google?

Tags: wordpress, sitemap, search-engine-indexing, google-index

I generated a new sitemap for my (WordPress) website with the Yoast SEO plugin.

However, Google shows the old sitemap in search results, so how long do I need to wait to see the new sitemap indexed?

Comment: That time period will vary from site to site and no one can tell exactly when it will be.

Comment: Google does not use the sitemap to index your site if Google can crawl your site properly. It will use the sitemap to audit the pages it finds while crawling your site to ensure that it can find your pages. If it can, then you will find that the sitemap is largely ignored. Do not look at the metric of pages indexed from your sitemap in Search Console. It is a junk metric and often very disappointing. It will go up and down and never really seem to make sense. So, please, ignore it. Cheers!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sitemaps are not indexed by Google per se. Instead, they inform the Google spider what pages, posts, tags, categories, authors, etc. are accessible to the spider and Google will then change its behavior accordingly.

Google shouldn't show a sitemap in the search results, though (at least not an XML-based one). If your previous sitemap was an HTML page or something else that Google would treat as a document and it is still publicly accessible, expect it to continue to show up until you remove it.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is go add and verify your site's name and url then submit your new sitemap to Google.

To do so:

1. Sign up with [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters)
2. Add property
3. Verify Ownership (upload a file to site root folder or server login
   credentials)
4. Submit sitemap
5. Fetch as Google
6. Submit  to index

After doing this I have seen sites start showing the update results within 30 minutes on the search engines.

[image]

[image]
[image]